# how to save video in IOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios7

I used the following code to save video in the photo library,but it is not working IOS7.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:urlVideo])
{
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:urlVideo completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (error) {
                [self ShowMessage:@"Failed to create movie ! It may be due to video quality,please try again/"  andTitle:@"ERROR:" andButtonTitle:@"Close"];
                 [self EnableView];
            }
            else {
                [self ShowMessage:@"Movie created successfully" andTitle:@"Movie Status" andButtonTitle:@"Ok"];
                [self EnableView];
                }
             });
         }];
}
```

I used this method also,but this method also fails to save video in IOS7

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (exportPath, [GlobalMethods sharedInstance], @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Please let me know if is there any modification that needs to be made in this method only or is there any other method for storing video in IOS7. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way...

```
#pragma mark - ImagePicker Controller Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
        NSString *sourcePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);
}
```

**Let me know if you have any problem**

Comment: You can see in my question,I already used this method and it is not working.